# Find maximum intensity count from gray scale 16 bit tiff image

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, tiff, 16-bit

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlpN8.png)I have a 16 bit tiff image.  I would like to get following information from the image

1. maximum intensity count.
2. even though my bit size is 16 bit, why is my color bar restricted to 256 or 8 bits.
3. histogram
   I have written a sample code to do the same and I do not know what are the numbers on x and y axis represent. Could you please help me with this
4. import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   ```
   import matplotlib.image as mpimg



    import numpy as np

   image = mpimg.imread('r1Ls01N000001.tif')

   plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')

   plt.colorbar()

   plt.show()

   plt.hist(x=image.ravel())

   plt.show()

   imax=np.max(image)

   print(imax)
   ```

Result
Imax value will be displayed as 264, is the 264 intensity count or bit number?
[Resulting image from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s4sC.png)

Comment: You have shared a 16-bit PNG rather than a TIFF. The maximum intensity is 4224.

Comment: might be a mistake while uploading, I will check that. But, how did you get that number 4224, I am interested in that.

Comment: With **ImageMagick**, using `magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE | grep -i max`

Comment: Thank you for suggesting imagemagick. I am running imagemagick on a windows and I am getting error that grep -i max is not recognised as an internal or external command?  is there a different command for Windows OS

Comment: I don't use Windows, but think you want `magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE.TIF | FINDSTR "max" /I`